# SharePoint Audit Log Help

Tags: sharepoint-online, audit-log-reports

I'm trying to understand how to read my SharePoint audit log. We had someone change the permission of a specific group on a folder.  When I pull the audit log it shows that the folder permission was updated "Security Role Bind Update) but it doesn't show how it was updated.  Several people over the last 90 days have updated permissions on the folder and we're trying to specifically find the user who updated the specific group and changed it from contribute to view only, but I don't see a way to find that information.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can only find all the users who have modified permissions in this site collection.

Detailed actions on permission changes are not supported.

References:

[View audit log reports.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527)

[Audit log information and SharePoint reports.](https://vox.veritas.com/t5/Data-Insight/Audit-log-information-and-SharePoint-reports/td-p/743586)